# How to run a fake quantized graph on a gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a quantized mobilenet downloaded from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md), This graph contains fake quantization nodes during training, to simulate test time output. I want to collect output from the last pointwise convolutional layer of this network.

The quantized frozen model contains additional fc,softmax etc layers that are of no use for my application.

I have the following code for loading the graph.

```
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    # We load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the
    # unserialized graph_def
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    # The name var will prefix every op/nodes in your graph
    # Since we load everything in a new graph, this is not needed
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="prefix")
return graph

graph1 = load_graph("./quantized_fake.pb")

input = graph1.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/input:0')
output = graph1.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise/Conv2D_Fold:0')
```

Then run using sess.run() , however i observe the output of the convolution layer is not quantized(8 bits) as it should be when it will be running on a mobile.

How can i produce the same output as would be produced on a mobile device while running the code on my pc.

Can the tflite files be used for inference on pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TensorFlow fake quantized graph isn't actually quantized, it has [FakeQuantization operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_guides/python/array_ops#Fake_quantization) inserted that emulate quantization. These are only converted to a fully quantized operations by TensorFlow Lite. This is why running the TensorFlow fake quantized graph will only result in float values not quantized values.

TensorFlow Lite quantization is currently CPU-only, and can be run on the CPU of a PC. Here is an [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/label_image), of how to invoke the TFLite interpreter to run on your PC.